# How to expose port 22 via NGINX Ingress Controller?

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes Cluster with a NGINX Ingress Controller. In the cluster I have deployed a [Gitea](https://gitea.io/) POD. The Web UI and the HTTPS access is exposed via an Ingress object like this one:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: gitea-service
  namespace: gitea-repo
spec:
  selector:
    app: gitea
  ports:
  - name: gitea-http
    port: 3000
  - name: gitea-ssh
    port: 22
---
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: git-tls
  namespace: gitea-repo
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - git.foo.com
    secretName: tls-gitea
  rules:
  - host: git.foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: gitea-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

This works all fine for HTTPS.

But Gitea also provides a SSH access through port 22. My Question is, how can I tell the NGINX Ingress Controller to route also port 22 to my pod?

As far as I understand I should patch my NGINX controller deployment with something like that:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: controller
        # defind cusotm tcp/udp configmap
        args:
        - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/tcp-configmap-giteassh

        ports:
         - name: ssh
           containerPort: 22
           protocol: TCP
```

and providing a config map pointing to my gitea service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-configmap-giteassh
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  22: "gitea-repo/gitea-service:22"
```

Do I need also an additional Ingress configuration in my Gitea POD now?

I wonder if this is the correct approach. Why I am forced to define this in the NGINX controller and not in my POD namespace as I do for HTTP? This would mean that for each POD exposing a TCP port other than HTTP I have to adjust my Ingress NGINX Controller?

Comment: I have updated my answer, could you please try again with this solution and let me know if it works for you ?

Answer (score 7):

I decided to improve my answer by adding more details and explanations.
I found your [blog post](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2021/02/25/running-gitea-on-kubernetes/) which contains all the information I need to reproduce this problem.

In your example you need **TCP traffic** to pass through on port `22` (it is TCP protocol).
NGINX Ingress Controller doesn't support TCP protocol, so additional configuration is necessary, which can be found in the [documentation](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2021/02/25/running-gitea-on-kubernetes/).
You can follow the steps below to expose the TCP service:

1. Create a `ConfigMap` with the specified TCP service configuration.
2. Add the `--tcp-services-configmap` flag to the Ingress controller configuration.
3. Expose port `22` in the `Service` defined for the Ingress.

---

*Ad 1.* We need to create a `ConfigMap` with the key that is the external port to use and the value that indicates the service to expose (in the format `<namespace/service name>:<service port>:[PROXY]:[PROXY]`).
**NOTE:** You may need to change `Namespace` depending on where the NGINX Ingress controller is deployed.

```
$ cat ingress-nginx-tcp.yml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-tcp
  namespace: default  
data:
  "22": gitea-repo/gitea-service:22
```

*Ad 2.* After creating the `ConfigMap`, we can point to it using the `--tcp-services-configmap` flag in the Ingress controller configuration.
**NOTE:** Additionally, if you want to use a name (e.g. `22-tcp`) in the port definition and then reference this name in the `targetPort` attribute of a Service, you need to define port `22` (see: [Defining a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service) documentation).

```
$ kubectl get deployment ingress-nginx-controller -oyaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
spec:
...
  template:
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - /nginx-ingress-controller
        - --tcp-services-configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-tcp
...
```

*Ad 3.* Then we need to expose port `22` in the Service defined for the Ingress.

```
$ kubectl get svc -oyaml ingress-nginx-controller
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 22-tcp
    nodePort: 30957
    port: 22
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 22
...
  type: LoadBalancer
...
```

Finally, we can check if it works as expected by creating a new repository on the command line:
**Note:** We need to have a gitea user with the proper SSH keys associated with this account.

```
$ git add README.md
$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master (root-commit) c6fa042] first commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 README.md
$ git remote add origin git@<PUBLIC_IP>:<USERNAME>/repository.git
$ git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 211 bytes | 211.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: . Processing 1 references
remote: Processed 1 references in total
To <PUBLIC_IP>:<USERNAME>/repository.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
```

In addition, we can log to the NGINX Ingress Controller Pod and check if it is listening on port `22`:

```
$ kubectl exec -it ingress-nginx-controller-784d4c9d9-jhvnm -- bash
bash-5.1$ netstat -tulpn | grep 22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: So far I think I understand the scenario. I have install NGINX Ingress controller directly. And when I try to apply the patch (as in my question) I always get the error: `--tcp-services-configmap=ingress-nginx/tcp-configmap: No such file or directory`

Comment: As I can see your ConfigMap is named `tcp-configmap-giteassh`, not `tcp-configmap`. Check if you have this ConfigMap in `ingress-nginx` namespace: `kubectl get cm -n ingress-nginx`

Comment: yes this is a typo in my question. I changed the name and I verified that the configmap exists in the ingress-nginx namespace. But I sill got the error.

Comment: Your `args:` section in NGINX controller Deployment doesn't look good, you should have much more items there. Look at [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.44.0/deploy/static/provider/baremetal/deploy.yaml) under `ingress-nginx-controller` Deployment. 
Maybe you overwritten something by accident.

Comment: Yes I only show the patch file here. But some strage reason still the configmap is not working for me.

Comment: When you patch your NGINX Ingress controller, you probably delete all other items from the `args` section and `--tcp-services-configmap` is the only item there - this can definitely cause an error.
Can you confirm this by describing your patched Pod ?

Comment: I followed your instruction but got an issue when I tried to ssh --> "ssh -Tv git@gitea.127.0.0.1.nip.io " Error: "kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer"

Answer (score 0):

The provided solution by matt_j is correct.

Just an addition for anyone who has configured ingress to use proxy protocol, you need to add `:PROXY` suffix to the service address in the configMap, so it becomes:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-tcp
  namespace: default  
data:
  "22": gitea-repo/gitea-service:22:PROXY
```