# Nginx Ingress Resource Not Allowing "ssh" Access from URL

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, nginx, ssh, nginx-ingress

I have an `Ubuntu` docker container that I deployed on Kubernetes. The container exposes port `22` in it and runs the ssh client so that a user can ssh into. The goal is to deploy and allow the pod to be exposed via an ingress such that you can ssh into the pod via the URL:

Expected behavior:

```
# ssh command
ssh user@vm.my-domain.com -p 22

# It requests password and you provide it and you're in
```

What is currently happening is that I'm getting the connection hanging and timing out with the error below:

```bash
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to vm.daba-dev.dabafinance.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host vm.daba-dev.dabafinance.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

Interestingly, if I port-forward the service on my local machine and use the port-forwarded endpoint, it works:

```bash
# Port-forward
kubectl port-forward svc/vm -n daba 6060:2222

# On another terminal I login
ssh vagrant@localhost -p 6060  

# That works and I'm in:
ED25519 key fingerprint is SHA256:********.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '[localhost]:6060' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
vagrant@localhost's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.231-137.341.amzn2.x86_64 x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

I am stuck, why I am unable to `ssh` via the Ingress Endpoint but able to do so with only `port-forward`

Configurations below:

- Kubernetes manifests

```yaml
# deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: vm
  namespace: vm-ns
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: vm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: vm
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vm
        image: vm
        ports:
        - containerPort: 22
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      restartPolicy: Always

# ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "vm"
  namespace: "vm-ns"
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  labels:
    app: vm
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - vm.my-domain.com
    secretName: ssl-vm-prod
  rules:
  - host: vm.my-domain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: 'vm'
              port:
                number: 22.     # some instances I use port 2222
# Service
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: vm
  namespace: vm-ns
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: vm.my-domain.com
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 22
      targetPort: 22
  selector:
    app: vm
  type: ClusterIP
```

- Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:focal
# FROM ubuntu:20.04-systemd
# FROM eniocarboni/docker-ubuntu-systemd:focal

# ENV container docker
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y

# Install prerequisites
RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl && \
    apt-get install -y openssh-client vim fuse-overlayfs && \
    apt-get install -y ssh sudo libffi-dev systemd

# Install Docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com -o get-docker.sh
RUN sh get-docker.sh

# # Generate SSH keys
# RUN ssh-keygen -A

# Create the vagrant user
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash vagrant && echo 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd

# Grant sudo privileges to the vagrant user
RUN usermod -aG sudo vagrant

# Allow passwordless sudo for the vagrant user
RUN echo 'vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' > /etc/sudoers.d/vagrant

# Grant access to the docker.sock file
RUN usermod -aG docker vagrant

# Configure SSH server
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd
RUN echo 'PermitRootLogin yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo 'PasswordAuthentication yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

# Set up the SSH password for the vagrant user
RUN echo 'vagrant:vagrant' | chpasswd

# Configure cgroups for Docker
RUN echo 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy=false"' >> /etc/default/grub

# Install Kind
RUN curl -Lo /usr/local/bin/kind https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/dl/v0.18.0/kind-linux-amd64 && \
    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kind

# Install kubectl
RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl" && \
    chmod +x kubectl && \
    mv kubectl /usr/local/bin/

# Expose SSH port
EXPOSE 22

# Start SSH server in the background
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D &

# Run the Docker daemon as a foreground process
CMD dockerd

CMD ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

- Environments

- cloud provider: `AWS`
- Kubernetes environment: `AWS EKS`

Comment: Possibly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66367867/how-to-expose-port-22-via-nginx-ingress-controller

Comment: as mentioned, it is a duplicate. The key is to make sure the ingress uses the TCP protocol, not HTTP/S. SSH is over TCP not HTTP/S